# In javascript, what is the difference between '\' and '\n'?

Tags: javascript, line-breaks

I figure that both \ and \n can be used as a line break. What is the difference?

EDIT: Sorry I **realized that I was wrong**. The tutorial was talking about / as a line break for the programmer, which wasn't displayed, i.e:

```
alert("Hi \
there");
```

Comment: `alert("foo\nbar"); alert("foo\bar"); alert("foo\\bar")`. Dunno what you're talking about.

Comment: How do you figure that `\\` can be used as a line break?

Comment: Please vote to close, as I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\n` is the only correct escape code for a newline (short of using things like `\u000a` or similar).

Note that the below code does not actually insert line breaks (would still need the actual `\n` escape code):

```
var foo = 'qwertyuiopasdfghjkl\
qwertyuiopasdfghjkl\
qwertyuiopasdfghjkl';
```

The result is 'qwertyuiopasdfghjklqwertyuiopasdfghjklqwertyuiopasdfghjkl'. I also don't recommend the above code because indenting the continuation lines causes problems with unwanted spaces in your string. One good alternative, though, is:

```
var foo = [
    'qwertyuiopasdfghjkl',
    'qwertyuiopasdfghjkl',
    'qwertyuiopasdfghjkl'
].join('\n');
```

Comment: rather than creating an array and joining it, why not just use concatenation? `var foo = 'qwertyuiopasdfghjkl' + 'qwertyuiopasdfghjkl' + 'qwertyuiopasdfghjkl';` -- You can place the concatenation operator at the end of or at the beginning of a line and it's perfectly valid syntax.

Comment: @Andy E: If it matters, that's twice as fast as the join. Of course, the backslash is even faster...

Answer (score 7):

A slash at the end of a line inside a string allows you to write the rest of the string on the following line. The resulting string won't actually contain a line break at that point. It is purely used to help make the source code more readable.

```
var foo = "This string \
has only \
one line.";

// Result:
// This string has only one line.
```

A "\n" actually inserts a linebreak.

```
var bar = "This string has\ntwo lines.";

// Result:
// This string has
// two lines.
```

Answer (score 1):

`\n` is a way of writing a new line (line break). So, `"Hello World!\nHow are you?"` would output like this:

```
// Hello World!
// How are you?
```

instead of this:

```
// Hello World!How are you?
```

You can use the "\" before other letters too... like `\t` which is a tab. or `\\` which makes a back-slash. But just entering `\` in a string will output nothing.